# To to know which key not found in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

I am using pycassa. I am requesting some columns from a row:

```
cf.get(rowKey, column_start=column_start, column_finish=column_finish)
```

If specified row key or any of start and finish column keys do not exist, NotFoundException is raised.
Is there a way to determine which key wasn't found - row key or column key (name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the near future a NotFoundException will not be returned when a key exists but an empty slice is returned; that should disambiguate the result.

I've opened https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa/issues/50 to address this.

In the meantime as a workaround, upon getting a NotFoundException, you can try:

```
cf.get(rowKey, column_count=1)
```

And if a NotFoundException is not raised, you know that the key exists and the row is not empty.